# Django TreeNodeChoiceForm update

Tags: python, django

first please look at code:

`views.py`

```
def transaction_add(request, form_class=TransactionForm, template_name='budget/transactions/add.html'):
    if request.POST:
        #nothing important, this part works
    else:
        form = form_class()
        #form.declared_fields['category'] = Category.objects.users(request.user.pk) 
    return render_to_response(template_name, {
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

`forms.py`

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # Replace category in the model with hieararchial category list
    category = TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('transaction_type', 'notes', 'category', 'amount', 'date')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category'] = self.fields['category'].get_queryset().filter(user_id=args[0]) #just temporary, without check. 
    def save(self):
        super(TransactionForm, self).save()
```

Now I try describe my problem. I call `transaction_add(...)` and then my form is going to create ( after GET ) by `form= form_class()`. I expect in `category` field i will have only categories created by user which is logged in. Unfortunately i had there all existing categories. I tried to ovveride `__init__` method but my `TreeNodeChoiceField` has all categories from db. I also try change it out of constructor ( now is commented ) but it still has not expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, looks like you're overriding the form field in the `__init__`.

Change your forms.py like so:

```
class TransactionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # Replace category in the model with hieararchial category list
    category = TreeNodeChoiceField(queryset=Category.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Transaction
        fields = ('transaction_type', 'notes', 'category', 'amount', 'date')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Get the user
        user_id = kwargs.pop('user_id')
        super(TransactionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        categories = self.fields['category'].queryset
        # Use the user to filter categories by user
        # Only change the queryset of the category field
        self.fields['category'].queryset = categories.filter(user=user_id) #just temporary, without check.

    def save(self):
        super(TransactionForm, self).save()
```

Basically the form now takes an extra keyword argument when creating an instance, the keyword argument is called `user_id`.
Then we use that user id to filter the categories and assign the resulting queryset to the category field queryset vs overriding the whole field.

In order for the above to work you also need to modify how you instantiate the form (in your view) like so:

```
if request.POST:
        #nothing important, this part works
    else:
        # Here we pass user_id keyword argument to the form
        form = form_class(user_id=request.user.pk)
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I fight with it 2 days. I am almost sure i tried something like You post here, but it does not work.